# How to delete (leftover) Windows partition on macOS Catalina?

Tags: windows, partition, startup, bluetooth, diskutil

I just bought a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 Unibody.
It seems to run a fresh Catalina install though I encountered a Bluetooth issue the other day (wouldn't find the Bluetooth device) and decided to clear the NVRAM. After doing so, the MacBook weirdly booted into a Windows recovery mode. I rebooted eventually and was able to choose the Catalina boot option with CMD + R. I assume there was a Windows install on here at some point in the past.

What I would like to do now though is get rid of all traces (partitions etc.) related to the former Windows install. After doing that, I intend to also update the MacOS to a newer one.

But first, can anyone please let me know how I can delete everything Windows related on the drive? Any help is greatly appreciated!

disk util list:

```
 ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:           Windows Recovery                         629.1 MB   disk0s1
   2:                        EFI NO NAME                 1.1 GB     disk0s2
   3:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         254.2 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +254.2 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume Macpro - Daten          19.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 26.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macpro                  778.2 KB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Macpro                  11.1 GB    disk1s6
```

Comment: It sounds like you're just using whatever install the previous owner was using. This is not the way forward; you should completely wipe the Mac before you use it, otherwise any apps on it & even the OS itself do not belong to you. At some point it will ask for the previous user's Apple ID & password to update or change something… & you won't have it.

Comment: See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065). The previous owner should have done this, as they haven't you need to start from 8.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the Bluetooth topic.  This site is on topic per question.  If the BT issues still persist after resolving your partition issues, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Wouldn't following the instructions given in your previous comments result in only erasing data stored in `disk0s4`. In other words, the partition locations and sizes would remain unchanged.

Comment: Trainwreck990: I believe Catalina is the latest version of macOS that Apple provides for your model Mac. No 2012 MacBook Pro models appear in [the list for Big Sur](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211238).

Comment: @DavidAnderson - no. Instructions say Erase disk, from Internet Recovery - that's the entire drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The instructions ask the user to only select from volumes show in the Disk Utility, then select the Erase button. The user is then prompted for a Name and Format. This does not result in any changes to the partitioning. To erase the entire drive, a user would need to first select the drive, next press the Erase button, then enter the Name, Format and Scheme. Selection of the drive does not occur anywhere in the instructions. Note to the OP: you may have to select "Show All Devices" in order to view the drives in the Disk Utility sidebar.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - ah, I see what you mean. I'm not used to the stupid hidden devices bit. I saw it was choosing the topmost item, with a closed reveal arrow. I'm losing faith in Apple's ability to make things easy for the user, I really am.